# get var name interpolated when evaluating splatter Tcl

Tags: tcl, eval

This is a rather simple one to ask. Just to clarify, I am working  Tcl 8.5.
I want to get variable interpolation done:

```
>set p "puts me"
>puts $p
puts me
>{*}$p
me
```

So this works fine. Now I want a string that says puts $varname to work, and that fails.

```
>set k {puts $p}
>{*}$k
$p
```

I want Tcl to output the value of var p. Using "evil eval" gets it done:

```
> eval $k
puts me
```

How can I get the eval behaviour w/o using eval?
Thanks.

Comment: Is eval evil?  Short answer: no (http://wiki.tcl.tk/1017)

Comment: Why do you want eval behavior without eval? What's wrong with using eval?

Comment: I'd use `eval` in this case: while it's often troublesome, it's the _right tool_ here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Multi-word values

Need to subst each item in the list otherwise multi-word values would become parameters.

```
set p {What is Awesome?}
set k {puts $p}
set len [llength $k]

# Must subst each item in the list in order
# to execute k properly.
for {set i 0} {$i < $len} {incr i} {
        lset k $i [subst [lindex $k $i]]
}
{*}$k
```

Output:

```
./puts.tcl
What is Awesome?
```

## Single Word Values

Use subst to do variable substitution.

puts.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set p Awesome
set k {puts $p}
{*}[subst $k]
```

output:

```
./puts.tcl
Awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the proc and uplevel commands.

```
set me {yo yo}
set p {puts $me}

proc doit {} "uplevel 1 {$p}"

doit
```

Comment: You don't need a proc for this: just to it in the current level: `uplevel 0 $p`

Comment: Nice! I did not think about that.

Comment: @user1455003, no, `subst` is quite valid.

Comment: There's no real difference between `eval` and `uplevel 0`.

Comment: I was under the impressions (could be mistaken) that eval stops byte coding, hence making the code very slow. If I am wrong, then it is not evil, and I am a daffer.